# Square root on dask series

Tags: python, dask

I have the following code trying to calculate the square root of a dask series

```
my_dask_df['a_column'] = numpy.sqrt(my_dask_df['a_column'])
```

What I get is the following exception:

```
ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.
```

How can I calculate the square root of a dask series?

Comment: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2690 Looks like you have to use [dask.array.sqrt](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html?highlight=sqrt#dask.array.sqrt) instead of `np.sqrt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the `**` operator or the `da.sqrt` function

```
df.x ** 0.5
# or 
import dask.array as da
da.sqrt(df.x)
```